# Given fixed sequence $a_n$ and random sequence $\omega_n$, what does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \omega_n a_n$ converge mean?

Tags: probability

Let $a_n$ be a fixed sequence of real numbers. Consider the space $\Omega= \{\pm 1\}^\infty$. Consider a sign sequence $\omega_n \in \Omega$, such that $P(\{\omega_i= 1\}) =  P(\{\omega_i = −1\}) = 1/2$, where $\omega_i$ is the $i$th component of the infinite sequence $\omega_n$. Then what does it mean by saying $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \omega_i a_i$$ converges ?

I’m a bit confused on the convergence when the randomness plays a part.

For example, in the case of $a_n=1/n$, if $\omega_n$ always choose $1$, the sum diverges; if $\omega_n=(-1)^n$, the sun converges; what would it be when $\omega_n$ is random? How to define it?

Comment: It means that probability that it converges is equal to $1.$

Comment: There are several notions of convergence, namely convergence in distribution, convergence in probability, almost sure convergence, convergence in mean. In general none of these are equivalent to each other. More here: [convergence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables)